Is this a sin? I took rocks
I said to one of my family members,  I wish I could have these types of rocks when I was in the parking lot of a Walmart because I want them outside my yard and so my dad he said I'll take them for you and I said no no don't but he did and my grandma was helping too so I did anyway we took 4 bags of rocks from the parking lot from a store is this a sin? They aren't crystals or anything but I felt guilty maybe it's stealing even if it's these rocks..
